Leveraging AWS textractor results in an output to a csv file that has inconsistent row lengths
// Function is used to get the rows in the column map The example for synchronous document analysis collects table information from a call to AnalyzeDocument. The example for asynchronous document analysis makes a call to StartDocumentAnalysis and then retrives the results from GetDocumentAnalysis as Block objects.
Table information is returned as Block objects from a call to AnalyzeDocument. For more information, see Tables. The Block objects are stored in a map structure that's used to export the table data into a CSV file.
def get_rows_columns_map(table_result, blocks_map):
    rows = {}
    scores = []
    for relationship in table_result['Relationships']:
        if relationship['Type'] == 'CHILD':
            for child_id in relationship['Ids']:
                cell = blocks_map[child_id]
                if cell['BlockType'] == 'CELL':
                    row_index = cell['RowIndex']
                    col_index = cell['ColumnIndex']
                    if row_index not in rows:
                        # create new row
                        rows[row_index] = {}
                    
                    # get confidence score
                    scores.append(str(cell['Confidence']))
                        
                    # get the text value
                    rows[row_index][col_index] = get_text(cell, blocks_map)
    return rows, scores

// Function is used to get the text
def get_text(result, blocks_map):
    text = ''
    if 'Relationships' in result:
        for relationship in result['Relationships']:
            if relationship['Type'] == 'CHILD':
                for child_id in relationship['Ids']:
                    word = blocks_map[child_id]
                    if word['BlockType'] == 'WORD':
                        if "," in word['Text'] and word['Text'].replace(",", "").isnumeric():
                            text += '"' + word['Text'] + '"' + ' '
                        else:
                            text += word['Text'] + ' '
                    if word['BlockType'] == 'SELECTION_ELEMENT':
                        if word['SelectionStatus'] =='SELECTED':
                            text +=  'X '
    return text

// Function is used to get the table csv results
def get_table_csv_results(file_name):

    with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:
        img_test = file.read()
        bytes_test = bytearray(img_test)
        print('Image loaded', file_name)

    # process using image bytes
    # get the results
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
    client = session.client('textract', region_name='placeholder', 
                            aws_secret_access_key='placeholder', 
                            aws_access_key_id='placeholder')
    response = client.analyze_document(Document={'Bytes': bytes_test}, FeatureTypes=['TABLES'])

    # Get the text blocks
    blocks=response['Blocks']
    pprint(blocks)

    blocks_map = {}
    table_blocks = []
    for block in blocks:
        blocks_map[block['Id']] = block
        if block['BlockType'] == "TABLE":
            table_blocks.append(block)

    if len(table_blocks) <= 0:
        return "<b> NO Table FOUND </b>"

    csv = ''
    for index, table in enumerate(table_blocks):
        csv += generate_table_csv(table, blocks_map, index +1)
        csv += '\n\n'

    return csv

// Function is used to generate the CSV table
def generate_table_csv(table_result, blocks_map, table_index):
    rows, scores = get_rows_columns_map(table_result, blocks_map)
    max_cols = max(len(row) for row in rows.values())
    table_id = 'Table_' + str(table_index)
    
    csv = f'Table: {table_id}\n\n'
    for row_index in sorted(rows.keys()):
        for col_index in range(1, max_cols + 1):
            csv += '{}'.format(rows[row_index].get(col_index, '')) + ","
        csv += '\n'
        
    csv += '\n\nConfidence Scores % (Table Cell)\n'
    score_index = 0
    for row_index in sorted(rows.keys()):
        for col_index in range(1, max_cols + 1):
            if score_index < len(scores):
                csv += scores[score_index] + ","
                score_index += 1
            else:
                csv += ","
        csv += '\n'
    
    csv += '\n\n\n'
    return csv


I don't see a question here.
